# Can I make syntax specific settings as global settings on Sublime?

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm using these settings on Sublime Text 3 for php files (Add them from `Preferences menu > Settings - syntax specific`)

```
// These settings override both User and Default settings for the PHP syntax
{
    "highlight_line": true,
    "line_padding_bottom": 15,
    "line_padding_top": 15,
    "bold_folder_labels": true,
    "tab_size": 4,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": false
}
```

Is there a way to use these as a global setting like for all file types, so I won't have to copy this snippet everytime I create a different file type?

Answer (score 0):

The hierarchy for the application of settings is as follows (taken from the [Official Documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/) on [Settings](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/settings.html))

1. Packages/Default/Preferences.sublime-settings
2. Packages/Default/Preferences (`<platform>`).sublime-settings
3. Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
4. `<Project Settings>`
5. Packages/`<syntax>`/`<syntax>`.sublime-settings
6. Packages/User/`<syntax>`.sublime-settings
7. `<Buffer Specific Settings>`

Any setting you want to be globally available should go in your regular user settings, which would be `Preferences > Settings` in the menu; you only need to use `Preferences > Settings - Syntax Specific` if you want some settings to apply only to a particular file type.